# Getting an error while starting airflow worker

Tags: airflow

I have installed airflow and trying to start the worker on the mac. But I am getting following error. Unable to identify what must be causing this issue.

```
[2018-05-02 15:37:11,458: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: TypeError("Invalid argument(s) 'visibility_timeout' sent to create_engine(), using configuration MySQLDialect_mysqldb/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.",)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
        self.blueprint.start(self)
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
        step.start(parent)
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 370, in start
        return self.obj.start()
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 320, in start
        blueprint.start(self)
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
        step.start(parent)
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/tasks.py", line 37, in start
        c.connection, on_decode_error=c.on_decode_error,
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 302, in TaskConsumer
        **kw
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 386, in __init__
        self.revive(self.channel)
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 408, in revive
        self.declare()
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 421, in declare
        queue.declare()
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 605, in declare
        self._create_queue(nowait=nowait, channel=channel)
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 614, in _create_queue
        self.queue_declare(nowait=nowait, passive=False, channel=channel)
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 649, in queue_declare
        nowait=nowait,
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 531, in queue_declare
        self._new_queue(queue, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 82, in _new_queue
        self._get_or_create(queue)
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 70, in _get_or_create
        obj = self.session.query(self.queue_cls) \
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 65, in session
        _, Session = self._open()
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 56, in _open
        engine = self._engine_from_config()
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 51, in _engine_from_config
        return create_engine(conninfo.hostname, **transport_options)
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 424, in create_engine
        return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/manishz/anaconda2/envs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 162, in create
        engineclass.__name__))
    TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'visibility_timeout' sent to create_engine(), using configuration MySQLDialect_mysqldb/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

Appreciate any help on it.

Thanks in avance
Manish

Comment: This seems to be connected to the SQLAlchemy framework which tries to set the argument `visibility_timeout`. Seems to me that this option is only valid for Redis, so your other packages might not be installed properly.

Comment: @tobi6 : Can you point out which packages should be removed ?

Comment: I would do it like this: if i'd experimented with Redis, I'd try to remove all those packages connected to it. Again, this was just a guess in the first place based on `Invalid argument(s) 'visibility_timeout' sent to create_engine()`.

Comment: Or maybe you are using a connection in your Airflow DAG or somewhere else which type is set to Redis but you have entered MySQL connection parameters. Try checking the connection settings in the Web UI and the default database connection in airflow.cfg